# Getting Unknown provider in my unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I get the following error when trying to unit test my angular service.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dbTranslateProvider.

I use Karma and Jasmine for testing and my code is packed with and WebPack. I'm new to Angular and Angular unit testing.

My unit test look like this (i'm not really testing anything yet):

```
describe("dbTranslate", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        var module = angular.module('ebcore');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

        var sut = $injector.get('dbTranslate');
        var test = $injector.get('$q');
    }));

    it("dbTranslate.translate", function () {
        $cacheFactory = function () { };
        $cacheFactory.get = function () { };
        //$dbTranslateCache = dbTranslate.dbTranslateCache($cacheFactory);
    });
});
```

The service i'm trying to test looks like this (typescript):

```
export class dbTranslate {
    static $inject = ['$q', '$http', 'dbTranslateCache'];

    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $http: ng.IHttpService, private dbTranslateCache: ng.ICacheObject) {

    }

    ensure(texts: string[]) {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();
        var missing = [];
        var values = {};

        texts.forEach(text => {
            var value = this.dbTranslateCache.get(text);
            if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
                missing.push(text);
            } else {
                values[text] = value;
            }
        });

        if (missing.length == 0) {
            deferred.resolve(values);
        } else {
            this.$http.post("/pub/texts/fetchText", missing).then(result => {
                for (var prop in result.data) {
                    if (result.data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        this.dbTranslateCache.put(prop, result.data[prop]);
                        values[prop] = result.data[prop];
                    }
                }
                deferred.resolve(values);
            }, error => {
                deferred.reject();
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    translate(text: string): string {
        return this.dbTranslateCache.get(text);
    }
}
```

If I try and debug my unit test I can see that the module._invokeQueue contains my service.

So any idea why can't I find my service through $injector? what am I missing?

Comment: Do no one have a suggestion to what the problem can be? I would really appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Found part of the problem. It works if I explicit state to use the _angular.mock.module()_ function. If I just use _angular.module()_ I guess it loads the regular angular module, thus the mock injector is not able to find my services. According to the examples and the mock documentation I should be able to just use the _module()_ function, but I can't and I dont undestand why - any idears?

Comment: Well, I believe this is because angular.module() loads the object where as module() loads the mock. module is shorthand for angular.mock.module().